# Compute polarizability after each step of relaxed scan in Gaussian 16

Tags: quantum-chemistry, gaussian, polarizability, semi-empirical-method

I am computing a relaxed 2D scan with Gaussian 16 in order to reproduce some computational data. I am interested in computing the dipole moment vector and the (static) polarizability matrix after each geometry optimization. Basically this is what Orca does automatically but I have to use Gaussian since I want to use the PM6 method. I read the manual and the IOPs but to be honest I did not understand if it is doable.

Alternatively, I would be happy if I could find a way to extract the geometries of the relaxed scan done in g16, in this way I could write a script to launch several single points to extract the data that I need.

Lastly, any suggestion about an alternative software (possibly free) that does this kind of calculations using the PM6/PM7 level of theory is welcome.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you tried running a small calculation with your scan settings and the keyword `Polar`? I would think this would be enough to get it print polarizability for each scan step (actually I had though the polarizability and dipole were printed by default even without `Polar`).

Comment: I tried, unfortunately the polarizability was printed just for the last point

Comment: @captin96, Did the provided answer solve your question? If yes, please indicate it as accepted. If not, please let me know, and I can expand the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This python script will read the logfile from the scan and generate the corresponding gaussian input files.

```py
import  numpy   as  np
import  sys     as  sys
import  typing  as  typing

class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, natoms:int, coords:list, atoms:list) -> None:
        self.natoms =   natoms
        self.coords =   coords
        self.atoms  =   atoms
        print(self.atoms)

def Gaussian_writeCOM(scanpoint:float, identifier:str, coordinates: Coordinates) -> None:
    with open("coord.{:0.0f}.com".format(scanpoint), "w") as comWriter:
        comWriter.write("%mem = 16GB\n%nprocs = 12\n%chk = {}.{:0.0f}.chk\n".format(identifier, scanpoint))
        comWriter.write("\n")
        comWriter.write("# mp2/cc-pvtz scf = qc\n")
        comWriter.write("\n")
        comWriter.write("single-point energy of {} at {:0.0f}\n".format(identifier, scanpoint))
        comWriter.write("\n")
        comWriter.write("0 1\n")
        for index, coord in enumerate(coordinates.coords):
            comWriter.write(" {:<10s}{:15.5f}{:15.5f}{:15.5f}\n".format(coordinates.atoms[index], coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]))

identifier  =   sys.argv[1]
logFile     =   sys.argv[2]
nAtoms      =   sys.argv[3]
initScan    =   sys.argv[4]
nPoints     =   sys.argv[5]
stride      =   sys.argv[6]

with open(logFile) as log:
    fullData        =   log.readlines()
    initscan        =   float(initScan)
    strideValue     =   float(stride)
    npoints         =   int(nPoints)
    natoms          =   int(nAtoms)
    scanPoints      =   np.arange(initscan, initscan + (strideValue * npoints), strideValue)
    coordObjects    =   []

    atoms   =   []
    # First find the atom names
    for lnumber, line in enumerate(fullData):
        if "Symbolic Z-matrix:" in line:
            atomData    =   fullData[lnumber+2 : lnumber+2+natoms]
            for atomline in atomData:
                atomline    =   atomline[0:2].split()[0]
                atoms.append(atomline)
                print(atomline)

    # Now read the coordinates
    for lnumber, line in enumerate(fullData):
        if "Input orientation" in line:
            coordData   =   fullData[lnumber+5 : lnumber+5+natoms]
        if "Stationary point found" in line:
            coords  =   []
            for line in coordData:
                line    =   line.split()
                coord   =   [float(x) for x in line[3:]]
                coords.append(coord)
            coordObject =   Coordinates(natoms=natoms, coords=coords, atoms=atoms)
            coordObjects.append(coordObject)

for index, coordObject in enumerate(coordObjects):       
    scanPoint   =   scanPoints[index] 
    Gaussian_writeCOM(scanpoint=scanPoint, identifier=identifier, coordinates=coordObject)
```

You will need to provide the total number of scan points as the input. Rest of the keywords are self-explanatory. Please change the route section to match your needs.

Comment: +1 and neat work with the code formatting man. I kind of involuntarily guessed that it was mostly you who is answering as soon as I saw the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is extremely helpful. I agree with @VandanRevanur, the code looks great